# Are variables that are passed to a function stored in contiguous memory positions?

Tags: c, parameter-passing, calling-convention, memory-layout, contiguous

I have written this little function:

```
int mayor(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {

   int mayor = n1;

   for(int *p=&n2; p<=&n5; ++p)

           mayor = *p;

   return mayor;

}
```

Is it guaranteed that the memory block that contains `n1` to `n5` is contiguous? Since I get the expected return value I hope so, but I want to know whether this is safe.

Comment: The compiler can do whatever it wants to: it can put some of them in the registers, some of them onto the stack (also in whatever order it prefers).

Comment: @ForceBru -- it is actually defined by the *calling-convention* of the API and differs greatly between architectures (e.g. x86 - pushed onto stack in reverse order, x86-64 - first six integer arguments (from the left) are passed in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9, in that order)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, right. The wording in my comment should be changed from "wants to" and "prefers" to "is required to", then.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - "standard" calling conventions (which the C standard doesn't define IIRC) mostly apply to functions that can be called from other compilation units. It appears this function could be (it's not declared `static`) but still, the most general rule for layout of parameters in memory is that there are no rules. There might not even be a "real" call at run-time since the function could be inlined. Because pointers are taken to some parameters the compiler will provide at least the illusion that they're in memory, though - but not necessarily the other parameters in-between.

Comment: @Steve314 - we have to be a little careful here. You are 100% correct that the C standard doesn't guarantee anything, and I agree. However, the compiler must produce valid assembly, and it is with the assembly ABI where the calling convention is guaranteed. (in fact the parameter order is what tells the assembler what to do with each parameter). So does the C standard guarantee anything? No. Is there a guarantee how parameters are passed and handled? Yes.

Comment: Then you can trust the way the parameters are passed and handled although the standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: "Since I get the expected return value I hope so" - why do you hope so? And why do you think a compiler cares? There is not even guaranteed they all **have** addresses. What you do is just broken code. Please get a good textbook and don't even think about such nonsense.

Comment: Btw: why don't you just `return n5;`; no need for all the other code in the function body (but then, why use a function at all?)

Comment: Ps: It would have helped a little bit if the OP added a sentence explaining the need for using such a function.  I.e. What he needs this function to return and why.  I think it's a good question anyway, and I don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I was being relatively careful, which is why I mentioned the issue of whether functions can be called across compilation units. Standard calling conventions are generally only used when the compiled function might be called from outside the current compilation unit. Otherwise, the compiler is free to use "custom calling conventions" (basically make up whatever it thinks will be most efficient) because it doesn't need to worry how callers will know how to call it. Though again, there's no reason to believe the function couldn't be called from another compilation unit.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - the point being that even when you know the platform and the ABI, you can't simply assume that the standard calling convention for that ABI will be used. There's exceptions - cases where the compiler can and probably will ignore the ABI, which after all is intended to allow callers to call the function, not to allow the function itself to do non-portable fragile hackish tricks with its parameters. I don't think non-compiler-writers should care whether OPs function *is* an exception, though it probably isn't (because it's not `static`, so the symbol will be in the object file).

Comment: @Steve314 - sorry we were miscommunicating, or I was. I was not saying that because we know the calling convention we can fiddle with things we shouldn't in C. I was saying at the function level, when the assembly is ultimately generated, the parameters will be passed via the calling convention, not that you can otherwise use that information within C for some nefarious purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The variables do not have even to be in the memory - they can be (all or only some) kept in the registers.

So your assumptions are wrong. If you want to have them in the contiguous chunks of memory you need to place them there yourself.

```
int mayor(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) 
{
  int parameters[5] = {n1,n2,n3,n4,n5};
```

Answer (score -1):

The parameters passed to a function c unless they are pointers are stored in Stack or in registers. The decision is allocation is dynamic by the program loader.

If your intention is to manage them as contiguous location and use loop, initiate an array with those elements.